# Doctrine order by string is case sensitive

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine

In my Symfony app, when I order by (with the query builder or anything else), the order is wrong.

If I do the request with my sql client, the result is right.

Example:

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('NAME', 'NAME');

    //Without uppercase
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY NAME ASC";
    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $categories = $query->getResult();
    dump($categories);
    /*
     * Return:
     *  - Bcd
     *  - abc
     *  - xyz
     */

    //With uppercase
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY UPPER(NAME) ASC";
    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $categories = $query->getResult();
    dump($categories);
    /*
     * Return:
     *  - abc
     *  - Bcd
     *  - xyz
     */
```

SQL Query with command line:

```
SQL> select NAME from Category order by NAME ASC;

NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------
abc
Bcd
xyz
```

Have you any ideas to fix this issue ?

Comment: Wrong? Show us some example rows in the current (wrong) order, and also in the wanted order. (Formatted text, please. No images.)

Comment: I have update the question, i want to have the same result when i do the request with my SQL client and with doctrine.

Comment: Are you 100% sure those two queries are made against the same table and database? It looks as if the collation were different for those two (`_ci` in the second case).

Comment: Yes, the code is a copy/paste from my controller

Comment: @ElliotBrl That's not what I asked What I asked is the database you are connecting in your "controller" is the same you are connecting to with your SQL client? Are you 100% sure of that?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's the same, i have only one